# Bitmask parsing in python using only standard library

Tags: python, parsing, bitmask

I want to parse an integer that is `unpack()`ed using the `struct` module to a list of truth values.

My current approach is this:

```
>>> [bool(int(_)) for _ in ("%8s" % str(bin(235)).split("b")[1]).replace(" ","0")]
[True, True, True, False, True, False, True, True]
```

It does the job, but is quite horribly convoluted. Anyone have an elegant and *pythonesque* way of doing the same?

Please note that above is just for an example and the bitmasks are not necessarily just 8 bits long, but the solution should work for an bitmask of arbitrary length (in practice it might be ok to just work with multiples of 4)

Comment: Did you read the question @DanD. ? I said I'm using `struct` - `unpack( "?")` does not parse a single bit but a C boolean value that is 8 bits!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arithmetic done elegantly, without C-style proceduralism:

```
size = 8
[bool(235 & (1 << size - i - 1)) for i in xrange(size)]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
>>> masklen = 8
>>> [bool(int(i)) for i in str(bin(235))[2:].rjust(masklen, '0')]
[True, True, True, False, True, False, True, True]
```

Comment: Ah, forgot about `rjust()` - this is better than my original approach,  but I'll wait for some time accepting in case a more elegant solution is posted :)

Answer (score 0):

So if you skip `pack` step and just use the integer:

```
def bitboollist(v,n=0):
        l = []
        t = v
        while t != 0:
                l.append(bool(t % 2))
                t = t / 2
        l.reverse()
        if len(l) == 0:
                l = [False]
        if n > len(l):
                l = [False]*(n-len(l)) + l
        return l
```

using that on an example `1234` yields:

```
>>> bitboollist(1234)
[True, False, False, True, True, False, True, False, False, True, False]
>>> bitboollist(1234,n=16)
[False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, True, True, False, True, False, False, True, False]
```